# userManager.CreateAsync System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity-3

We are trying to use Microsoft Account Authentication in an ASP.Net 5 project. We don't require local authentication and don't require user names.

In the ASP.Net 5 Template for a web application, after signing in with an external provider, control returns to `ExternalLoginCallback` in the AccountController.

If the user is not registered locally `ExternalLoginCallback` returns the user to a registration screen. I have attempted to modify `ExternalLoginCallback` to automatically register the new user as below.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(5, "User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return View("Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
            //ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            //ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
            //var email = info.ExternalPrincipal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            //return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = email });

            // The user has not previously logged in with an external provider. Create a new user.
            CreateUser(info);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
    }
```

CreateUser implements code copied from `ExternalLoginConfirmation` as it appears in the ASP.Net 5 Template for a web application.

```
        private async void CreateUser(ExternalLoginInfo info)
    {
        var email = info.ExternalPrincipal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = email, Email = email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                _logger.LogInformation(6, "User created an account using {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
            }
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }
```

An error is thrown on the line

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
```

The error is

```
System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. Additional information: Cannot access a disposed object.
```

I have rebooted my machine just in case it was 'just one of those things', but the error recurs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using an `async void` method is rarely a good idea and is the best way to introduce weird race conditions like the one you're experiencing: since your `CreateUser` method doesn't return a task, it can't be awaited by `ExternalLoginCallback` and the request completes before `CreateUser` has the time to execute the database operations (when the request completes, the DI system call `Dispose` on scoped dependencies like your EF context).

Update your `CreateUser` method to return a `Task` and await it from `ExternalLoginCallback` and it should work:

```
await CreateUser(info);
```